# Hybrid Database Relationships?

Tags: mysql, database, orm, relational-database, entity-relationship

What is a relationship called when there are three entities, `Table1` `Table2` and `Table3`

`Table1` has a One To One Relationship with `Table3`
`Table2` has a One To Many Relationship with `Table3`
`Table3` has two composite keys, `Table1ID` and `Table2ID`.

What is this relationship called? I'm trying to figure out how to model this in an ORM but because I don't even know what the relationship is, I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To me i looks like a special case of many to many relation

Comment: @joshido http://s14.postimg.org/uoo8xt1sx/Screen_Shot_2013_07_29_at_2_50_47_PM.png

Answer (score 0):

We'd normally refer to that as <strike>*reflexive* or</strike> *bi-directional*.

Handling this in an ORM is non-trivial.

If you could remove the `Table1ID` column from `Table3` (removing the foreign key pointing back), that would simplify the model. But that may not be an option for you.

Hibernate would refer to this as a *bi-directional association*; Hibernate only persists one "end" of that association; it won't maintain foreign keys in both directions.

---

**EDIT**

I reviewed the model diagram (from the link you provided in a comment).

It looks very much like the `personVehicle` table is an *association* table, between `person` and `vehicle`. This is the same pattern we would see in resolving a many-to-many relationship. Your model looks like a special case of a many-to-many, where one side of the relationship is constrained to just one.

In terms of keys, your model looks like this:

```
person 
  id    PK

vehicle
  id    PK

personVehicle
  person_id  PK, FK->person(id)
  vehicle_id PK, FK->vehicle(id)
```

If I understood what you are asking, you are wanting to represent a foreign key constraint on the `vehicle` table that points back to a row in the personVehicle table:

```
vehicle
  id    PK, FK->personVehicle(vehicle_id)
```

I don't know of any ORM that is going to maintain that type of bi-directional foreign key in the `vehicle` table for you automatically. (I don't think it's impossible to maintain the value in a foreign key column, it's not just possible to "declare" this association in a way where an ORM will maintain the foreign keys in both directions.

(Some databases, such as Oracle, allow us to create and maintain relationships like this, by allowing foreign constraints to be DEFERRED while we are inserting, updating and deleting, and postponing the checks on foreign key constraints until COMMIT.)

If there was a foreign key, from `vehicle`, pointing to a row in `personVehicle`, and there's a requirement that the row in `personVehicle` is required to refer back to the EXACT same row in the `vehicle` table (and not just some row) then you don't really need a foreign key in the `vehicle` table. The relationship is already represented sufficiently in the model by the foreign key in the `personVehicle` table.

If you need to enforce a constraint that a vehicle can be related to at most one personVehicle, that calls for a UNIQUE constraint on `personVehicle(vehicle_id)`. That represents the requirement sufficiently in the model.

If this is truly one-to-one, and you need a foreign key, then this would actually be equivalent to removing the `vehicle` table entirely, and merging the attributes from that table into the personVehicle table.

---

**EDIT**

My use of the term *reflexive* may be incorrect. I usually refer to a table that has a foreign key reference to a column in the same table as being *recursive*.

In terms of a relationship between *two* tables, where each table has foreign key that refers to the other table... in the case where row in t1 refers to a row in t2, and that row in t2 refers back to t1, not to just any row, but back to the EXACT same row that referred to it... I think of that in terms of the relationship being "reflected" back.

The relationship reflects back. But we don't use the term "reflection" since that term has a special meaning in Java. So, maybe the only term that is appropriate is "bi-directional".

The typical bi-directional one-to-one relationship is the row in one table points to a row in the other table, which points back to the EXACT same row in the original table:

For example:

```
t1          t2
id  t2_id   id   t1_id
--- -----   ---- ------
1   A       A    1
2   B       B    2
3   C       C    3
```

Another form would be where a row did not necessarily refer back to the same row that referenced it. (This is not usually limited to a one-to-one), but we still have foreign keys that point in both directions (from t1 to t2, and from t2 to t1)

For example:

```
t1            t2
id  t2_id     id  t1_id
--- -----     --- ----
1   A         A   2
2   B         B   3
3   C         C   1
```

In the first case, we have a requirement where a row has a foreign key value that refers ONLY to a row in the other table that refers back to original row. The relationship "reflects" back.

In the second case, we don't have that requirement.  If I start with row 1, it points to row A, which points back to row 2.

In terms of defining the foreign key relationships in the database, thee definition of the constraint is the same.  The difference is usually whether the foreign key columns can be NULL, or have to be UNIQUE.

I thought there was a term other than just "bi-directional" that distinguished the first case from the more general second case. I thought I had used the term "reflexive" or "reflective", but I may be mistaken.

In terms of a "recursive" relationship, where a foreign key points back to a row in the same table, that foreign key (almost) always refers to a DIFFERENT row in the table; it does not refer back to itself.

Comment: My model is http://s14.postimg.org/uoo8xt1sx/Screen_Shot_2013_07_29_at_2_50_47_PM.png. As you can see, a person can have many vehicles but a vehicle can belong to only one person. The junction table personVehicle holds personVehicle information and the relationship. I've tried Eloquent, I've looked at Propel and Doctrine, but it does not seem like an ORM is capable of handling this kind of relationship. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I looked into reflexive relationships and it appears that it is a table that has a relationship with itself and another table. But in this situation there are three tables and the third is simply a junction table. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Dingo Egret: my terminology could be off. I usually refer to a table that has a foreign key reference to a column in the same table as being *recursive*; I think in terms of a one-to-one relationship between two different tables, where each table has foreign key that refers back to the other as a reflection, the relationship reflects back. But we don't use the term "reflection", since that term has a special meaning in Java. So, maybe the only term that is appropriate is "bi-directional".